# Redux Reducer: Filter Out Duplicate Objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have a `groceryReducer` where I add `groceryItems` to. The format of each object that is added to the `groceryItems` array is listed below. I'm trying to use the `newSet` array method, but it's still adding them and not filtering out the duplicates. What am I doing wrong?

**groceryObject**

```
{
  title: "Chorizo Turkey Chili",
  subtitle: "Soup/Stew"
}
```

**groceryReducer**

```
// Action Type: Add Grocery Item
case 'ADD_GROCERY_ITEM': {

  return {
    ...state,
    groceryItems:  Array.from(new Set(state.groceryItems.concat(action.groceryObject))),

  }
}
```

**console.log**

```
groceryItems: Array(4)
  0: {title: "Chorizo Turkey Chili", subtitle: "Soup/Stew"}
  1: {title: "Chorizo Turkey Chili", subtitle: "Soup/Stew"}
  2: {title: "Chorizo Turkey Chili", subtitle: "Soup/Stew"}
  3: {title: "Chorizo Turkey Chili", subtitle: "Soup/Stew"}
```

Comment: If you are adding a new item to your grocery list, and the person wants multiple, like they add it 3 times, then shouldn't you have a count? Like :`{title: "Chorizo Turkey Chili", subtitle: "Soup/Stew", qty: 4}`. Then you just update the `qty` Based on if the `title` & `subtitle` are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Set` object will keep unique *references*, it doesn't compare properties of an object.

One way you could accomplish this is creating a set of titles and comparing those.

```js
case 'ADD_GROCERY_ITEM': {
  const titles = new Set(state.groceryItems.map(item => item.title));
  if (titles.has(action.groceryObject.title)) {
    // Already exists in state, don't add
    return state;
  }
  // doesn't exist in state, add it!
  return {
    ...state,
    groceryItems: state.groceryItems.concat(action.groceryObject)
  }
}
```